# Gradle "Duplicate class" error when adding uCrop and Cometchat libraries

Tags: android, gradle

When I add the UCrop library version 2.2.3 and Cometchat SDK version 1.6.+ I get the following error :

> Duplicate class okhttp3.Address found in modules okhttp-3.11.0.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0) and okhttp-3.12.0.jar (com.cometchat:pro-android-chat-sdk:1.6.0)

The problem is that none of the previously asked questions have answers that solved my problem because most of them use the 'compile' method which is now deprecated.

I read many questions here on stackoverflow about the same topic, including
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44913406/exclude-one-class-file-in-gradle-android-studio) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40883974/gradle-exclude-a-dependencys-package).

I've also tried excluding okhttp3 library from one of the packages so that only one is used , using

```
implementation('com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.3' )
    {       
exclude group: 'com.cometchat', module: 'okhttp3'
  }
```

I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me how excludes work in gradle and what's wrong with the code that I wrote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of excluding `okhttp3` from `com.cometchat` group  try doing this

```
implementation('com.cometchat:pro-android-chat-sdk:1.6.0') {
        configurations {
            compile.exclude module: 'okhttp'
        }
    }
```

The conflict is due to your both `UCrop` and `CometChat` dependencies internally uses `okhttp` library.To resolve this problem you have to exclude conflicting library.

> Excluding transitive dependency can be done two different ways.
>
> 1. Exclude transitive dependency by configuration
> 2. Exclude transitive dependency by dependency

To read more about `gradle dependency` conflict cause and solution you can check out this link 
https://www.concretepage.com/build-tools/gradle/gradle-exclude-transitive-dependency-example